# Encrypt local indexeddb database but not the data itself

Tags: encryption, web, local, pouchdb

We are using PouchDB the save our data locally. We want to make sure that data is saved securely.

If we are encrypting the data itself via a plugin it is not possible to query our DB because all the data is not readable anymore...

Is there a way to make sure data is saved securely without encrypting the data itself? Is it possible to encrypt the database as a whole?